# Followed Gazebo Model Plugin Tutorial however there is a Black Screen in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo-simu

Followed Gazebo tutorial (http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_model&cat=write_plugin) however when typing all the commands Gazebo appears like this[image]

Here is the output from running the server command
[image]

And here is the output from running the client command
[image]
Can you guys please assist me with how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the sdf version from 1.4 to 1.5 and now it works